# No graphics card

Tags: display, graphics-card, vga

Can you use a display port or vga to view the terminal on a computer without having a graphics card? I am looking to buy a Lenovo Server with a Xeon processor which doesn't have a graphics card. Will I have to buy a graphics card if I choose to buy the computer?

Comment: You might have a motherboard intended for "headless" operation.  Instead of the console on a video display & keyboard, use a serial console (over a RS232 link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hardware brochure does not list a discrete GPU, then most likely it will have an onboard GPU. Some sort of display adapter will always be available on the motherboard, otherwise how can customers use it?

If in doubt, look at the motherboard: does it have a port such as VGA? If yes, then you can output the display to somewhere

Answer (score 1):

The server will have at least a VGA port on it.  If it didn't, there would be no way to access the console.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use display port or vga to view the terminal , you dont need to have the graphics card. you only need graphic card when you are using high graphic movies or games and this also can be run by onboard graphics card but performance isnt good.